# How to replace/overwrite an arbitrary number of bits in an arbitrary position in an array of short with arbitrary bits from an integer

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have a function I'm trying to write of the following form (and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for — if this is a dup please just point me at the right place — even if it's not `int`s and `short`s but, say, `char`s and `int`s instead, that would be fine):

```
put_bits(short *array_of_short, int significant_bits, int bit_offset, int integer_to_append)
```

Where I overwrite the the `significant_bits` of `integer_to_append` at `bit_offset` in `array_of_short`.

I'd like to accomplish things by just overwriting (or bitwise oring, or overlaying, or replacing) bits to the position in the array (I don't want to add more elements to the array or allocate more memory) — i.e. it should be easily possible, but pretty inefficient, to just keep track of how many elements into the array the offset translates to, whether this falls on a boundary of the shorts and shift the bits of the integer to the appropriate offset and or them onto the appropriate short(s) — but that seems like loads of overhead and calculating more than I need to vs just oring the bits into the appropriate spot, but I'm kind of at a loss...

So, for example, I have an integer which will contain an arbitrary number of "significant" bits — let's say for this example there are 6.  So the values would be from 0 to 63

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

to

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1111
```

and I want to overlay (or bitwise or this) this to an arbitrarily sized array of `short` at an arbitrary point.  So if I had

Integer:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0001
```

Array of short:

```
0100 1000 0100 1100 : 1100 0010 0110 0000 : 0000 0000 0000 0000 : 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

and I wanted to append at position 42 to get:

```
0100 1000 0100 1100 : 1100 0010 0110 0000 : 0000 0000 0000 1000 : 0100 0000 0000 0000
```

If I'm totally off or I don't make sense, let me know too.

Comment: Could you define 'append' because I always thought it meant 'add to'.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, bad word choice on my part, more like overlay a section of the array, I don't actually want to reallocate memory or add elements, I want to be able to overlay the section of the array starting at the `bit_offset` with the `significant_bits` of the now badly mis-named `integer_to_append`. I edited a little to try to clarify, but will leave this comment here.

Comment: It would be a bit easier with an array of ints, then you would only need to touch 2 elements at most (now it's 3)

Comment: I think the word you are after is replace/overwrite bits. If you want to understand this problem, start by writing function which will just print current bits from array without replacing anything. Once you understand how that works, then start examining replacing those bits without changing any other bits.

Comment: Yep, that's the word(s)! Changed the ever growing title to reflect that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you actually want to treat your array as array of bits. There is no such structure in c as bit array of course, but you can implement it. [Here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html)  is example of bit array with int as base type. You can adopt this solution with short as base type, and then just set bit by bit something like that:

```
for( i = 0 ; i< sizeof(int)*8;++i)
{
       unsigned int flag = 1;
       flag = flag << i;
       if( int_num & flag)
           SetBit( array_of_short, bit_offset + i ); 
}

void  SetBit( short array_of_short[ ],  int k )
{
   array_of_short[k/16] |= 1 << (k%16);  // Set the bit at the k-th position in  array_of_short[i]
}
```

Comment: I like it, and I considered setting bit by bit on an element by element basis and that may be my best option (so, I'm not discounting this as the answer by a long shot, and its waaaay better then worrying about element boundaries as I posted above, so definitely a step in the correct direction) but I hoped/conjectured that there should be a better way and I did just find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264552/c-c-code-to-treat-a-character-array-as-a-bitstream) which I want to accomplish the corollary of (i.e. setting those bits instead of getting them)

Comment: is `bit in your int is 1` anything more fun than:
    `int test_bit_int( int *symbol,  int bit_to_read )`
    `{`
        `int mask = 1;`  

         `mask = mask << bit_to_read;`
         `if (bit_to_read <= sizeof(int)*8){`
             `if ( *symbol & mask )`
                 `return 1;`
             `else`
                 `return 0;`
        `}else{`
                `return 187;`
        `}`
    `}`

Comment: @l.j.cooper see my edit. anyway i don't understand 100% this part of your question, so decision when to set the bit is up to you

Comment: Yeah, looks like essentially the same thing... and really you've got the most convincing answer so far, its bit by bit, but that's fine it'll get the job done - I just was hoping it would be doable in one nice swoop. You understand the question just fine; its my contorted explanation/question that stinks... I'm checking this as the answer because it gets the job done and its a nice step more elegant than what I had, which is, really, what I was looking for... Thanks!